# Nonexistent ambiguous reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In a Visual Studio 2010 project, we had two identically named classes in two different namespaces that are both commonly included in ViewModels throughout the application.  One such class has since been deprecated and removed, but I'm getting an ambiguous reference error when directly referring to the remaining class, even though the old class no longer exists.

We basically have something like this:

```
using OurNamespace.UI.Common;
using OurNamespace.SomewhereElse;

// *snip*
SomeClass.SomeMethod();
```

Once upon a time, both of the above namespaces had a SomeClass, but we deleted the one in OurNamespace.UI.Common.  However, when building, we get the following error:

> 'SomeClass' is an ambiguous reference between 'OurNamespace.UI.Common.SomeClass' and 'OurNameSpace.SomewhereElse.SomeClass'

I've already tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding as suggested in answers to [this ambigous reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325841/ambiguous-reference), only to continue to see the error.  What's still lurking behind that makes it think the deleted class still exists for purposes of an ambiguous reference?  Even IntelliSense knows there's only one now.

Comment: A reference to the old class ?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk There's still a reference to the namespace that the old class used to be in (because it has other things in use), but the old class itself no longer has any extant references.

Comment: Ok from there have you tried : Rebuilding the old class too ? (I guess you did). Also is temporarily removing the reference solving the  issue ?

Comment: The old class exists only in source control now--it's been deleted from its project and the solution.

Comment: have you tried using the allegedly deleted class to see if it has indeed been deleted? if that throws an error all i could suggest is manually rebuilding the project to make sure you are not accidentally including a cached dll or something.

Comment: What I meant is actually have you temporarily removed the reference to the namespace that used to contain the old class to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Sounds like you have a copy of an assembly that you're referencing instead of referencing the project.  Try removing all the references to an assembly that *had* that type and re-add it.

Comment: How did you set the reference to the other assembly? Is it a simple reference to its project? It is *possible*, for example, that you have a reference to a debug dll, and you are building the release dll.

Comment: Ok, bear with me while I check each of these things.  It's a very large solution with dozens of projects, so builds and rebuilds even slower than you can imagine.

By the way, I should note that each of these two namespaces refer to separate projects within the same solution.  Places where I'm getting ambiguous references are in various other projects also within the solution.

Comment: If you look at your project references in your project settings you can use Object Explorer to check if the class is lurking in one of them.

Comment: @dr.mo Trying to use the deleted class by its full namespace path, it looks like it's ready to work and successfully rebuilt.  However, the code is very much not there in the other project, which has since been rebuilt and manually re-referenced.

Comment: @MatthewWatson And there it is, back from the dead, even though it was hiding from me in Solution Explorer!

Comment: @MatthewWatson Would you care to make an answer out of that? :-)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I've removed/renamed that namespace. I even tried clearing the Intellisense database. Still doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your project's references (via the `References` section of the `Solution Explorer` window), you can right-click the reference and select `View in Object Browser`.

This allows you to investigate the referenced assemblies to see if the offending class is still lurking in any of them.

Comment: Thanks - I'd accidentally dragged the file elsewhere in the project. Opening the Object Browser let me find what VS was pointing to, where I could diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

> There's still a reference to the namespace that the old class used to be in (because it has other things in use)

I think your problem is with the reference to the dll that used to contain the deleted class.

Simply remove the reference and re-add it. It should solve the issue.

Comment: "reference to a namespace", what is that?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk I tried both removing the namespace reference in the code and readding it (as its needed for other objects) and also removing the other project itself from the project references and re-adding it as well.  Neither seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Super old thread, but in VS2017 I had this happen and had to **restart VS** to get it fixed after I moved files between namespaces.